# delimiter to split csv file is not working in Python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a csv file with entries like:

```
00020000001000,gl3.h5,2,5,0,0,0,"1:15:29 PM",60.2350934,-138.29382304 etc.
00020010000000,gl3.h5,2,8,0,0,0,"1:16:24 PM",60.09523934,-138.2322304 etc.
00020000100000,gl3.h5,2,11,0,0,0,"1:17:05 PM",60.0345934,-138.2932582304 etc.
00020000000100,gl3.h5,2,4,0,0,0,"1:18:19 PM",60.090934,-138.2235382304 etc.
```

Now, I want to sort the rows in this file by the integer in column 3 (for example `5` in the first row, `8` in the second one).

My code so far looks like:

```
import csv
with open("line 1.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    sort = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(x[3]), reverse=True)
    print(sort)
```

But when I run the code it says `IndexError: list index out of range"`.

Why is the delimiter `,` not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have likely empty lines in your csv. Filter them out:

```
import csv
with open("line 1.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = [entry for entry in reader if entry]
    sort = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x[3]), reverse=True)
    print(sort)
```

Comment: What does the s before splitlines() mean? It works for x[0], but not for any other index

Comment: Sorry. Leftover form my tests. I used a multi-line string instead of a file. Fixed.